# Bootstrap JS script not working

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have a webpage, and I have all of the js scripts in the footer of the webpage, yet it is not letting me use the js functions of bootstrap, like using drop downs. The

Can anyone help?

I can't put the code here because of the character limit, but here is a paste bin:

http://pastebin.com/fzy6e5CZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that linking to scripts makes your page relatively slow. I would try using a CDN, here is the code to include the min. versions of those scripts through the CloudFlare CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.3/holder.min.js"></script>
```

Use the following for Bootstrap CSS

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Yes, this seemed to work. I still don't know why it wasn't working before though

Comment: Most likely because you forgot the `/` before linking to the file. Ex. `js/jquery.js` should be `/js/jquery.js`

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't realise I had to have that. Thank you for future reference though

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your jQuery and bootstrap .js file and check your file adding path is right. Your file destination exactly there where you trigger it?